# finger command not working?

Tags: linux, user-accounts

I am using amazon linux AMI on EC2 cloud.
chfn command is working fine and i am able to change finger information.
But finger command is not working.

Any clue to solve the issue?

```
# chfn testuser
Changing finger information for testuser.
Name []: James
Office []: Canada
Office Phone []: 123
Home Phone []: 234

Finger information changed.


# finger testuser
bash: finger: command not found

# yum provides finger
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security, update-motd
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
* amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
  amzn-main                                                                                                                             | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates                                                                                                                          | 2.3 kB     00:00
 finger-0.17-39.6.amzn1.i686 : The finger client
 Repo        : amzn-main
 Matched from:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try

```
yum provides finger
```

to discover which package on the amazon repositories contains the `finger` client. Then use `yum` to install the package.

Comment: thanks, i have updated question with yum provides finger..

Comment: yum install finger work fine for me.